# If expression inside try fails, Rmarkdown does not print the error message

Tags: r, r-markdown

Why in Rmarkdown, if the expression inside `try` fails, the error message is not printed, even though in chunk `error = TRUE`. Code is below, which does not print anything:

````
```{r, error = TRUE}
try(log("a"), silent = FALSE)
```
````

Comment: This chunk is working and it is throwing error in Console in RStudio. Let us know which version you are using. If you want errors to be printed in output files you have to use the chunk setup answered below.

Comment: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

Comment: It is throwing an error to Console, but neither to pdf nor to html.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to get the printed output

````
```{r}
try(log("a"))[1]
```
````

It will look like this in pdf [image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

Paste the below code in your `.rmd` file at the start to get the `errors` and `warnings` generated in the r chunks to `html output` or `pdf`.

````
  ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, error = TRUE, warning = TRUE)
  ```
````

This is not chunk specific its for all chunks inside `.rmd` file, this will print all the errors or warnings if any any at all in the r chunks written.

After adding the above chunk, you can `knit html or pdf` that will also show you the `errors and/or warnings` if any at all in `r chunk`.